# Reading a text file into a matrix

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

I have some very large text files with an unknown number of lines having the following structure:

```
word number word number
```

How can I read this into a matrix? I've tried

```
load("file.txt")
```

and I've tried (saw this solution at another forum)

```
reshape(textscan('file.txt', '%s'),4,[])
```

None of them works. The reshape function gives me the error:
"Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 4, not divisible into total number of elements, 1."

And load() gives error: Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file test1.txt

Comment: check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10946-readtext). This has always solved most of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `textscan` like

```
fid = fopen('file.txt','r');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %f %s %f'); %for string and floating point number
disp(C);
```

You can refer http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html

You can see this tutorial
http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/textscanDemo.html

It might be of help